# What theories of quantum mechanics can eschew global phase?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-states, quantum-measurements

Whilst reading the [quantum.country](https://quantum.country) essay by Michael Nielsen and Andy Matuschak, they mention (a bit further down from [here](https://quantum.country/qm#third-postulate-qm)) that there is formulations of QM that can completely ignore global phase factors - which feels natural, as they are completely non-measurable in reality, and their only application (as far as I know) is to inspire kickback systems (controlled-U gates) to be able to measure it using relative phase. However, I'm curious about what these theories that can ignore the global phase factor look like. How do they avoid the problem of all complex numbers having phase?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but if you want to be pedantic about it, quantum states are elements of a [complex projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space), which you can think of as the set of equivalence classes $[\psi]$ such that $x,y\in [\psi]$ iff $x=e^{i\phi}y$ for some phase $e^{i\phi}$. In this sense, the "global phase" is simply not a property of a state. It's just often practically easier to consider states as simple vectors in $\mathbb C^n$ and get rid of the global phase afterwards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quantum mechanics can be reformulated using not the state vectors $|\Psi\rangle$ but density matrices $\rho$. These density matrices are the outer product of the state vectors such that
$$
e^{i\phi}|\Psi\rangle e^{-i\phi}\langle \Psi| = |\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi| = \rho ,
$$
so you see that the global phase drops out.

See e.g. [Ref 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix) or "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information" by Nielsen and Chuang